# Is it okay to modify Ubuntu Linux 16.04's /etc/fstab after I initialized it?

Tags: ubuntu, fstab, reboot

I modified /etc/fstab after I initialized it on an Ubuntu Linux 16.04 system running on an Lenovo Thinkstation desktop. After it messed up my Ubuntu Linux 16.04 system causing it to go into emergency reboot status endlessly.

I would like to know what caused this mishap and how to fix /etc/fstab correctly so as to change the symbolic name.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[EDIT 5/24/2016 2:00PM by Frank]
The /etc/fstab changed from underneath me after the emergency reboot.

The original read like this:

```
Data1 /media/Data1 vfat defaults 0 1 

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=71f42e33-6984-4905-9932-17cd4adb7b41 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=0a3b409b-f7bf-4a22-a05f-0dc35e1bb111 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40267/discussion-on-question-by-frank-is-it-okay-to-modify-ubuntu-linux-16-04s-etc-f).

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it is okay to modify Ubuntu Linux 16.04's /etc/fstab after one initializes it.

I narrowed the cause of the problem where we modify  /etc/fstab  to sudo nano /etc/rc.local :

```
e.g. Add these lines before the exit line:
     sleep 30
     sudo mount -a
     exit
     exit 0
```

which were intended for the usb drive taking a long time to initiate , this automount may fail.